# How to read out cells of a Excelsheet in Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections, apache-poi

[image: 1]

Hello everyone,

i want to read cells from a Excelsheet and put the data in a Arraylist. But get i a `NullpointerException`. I am really frustated, because in an another Excelsheet it works but now not. The Excelsheet self is not empty or something like this.

Is there something what i don't see?

Here is my Code:

```
       List<Cell> gyro = new ArrayList();
       File filegyro = new File("./data/Gyro_convert.xlsx"); 
       FileInputStream fisgyro = new FileInputStream(filegyro);   
       XSSFWorkbook wbgyro = new XSSFWorkbook(fisgyro);
       XSSFSheet sheetgyro = wbgyro.getSheetAt(0);
       Iterator iteratorgyro = sheetgyro.iterator();


       while (iteratorgyro.hasNext()) {
           XSSFRow row = (XSSFRow) iteratorgyro.next();

           Iterator cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
           
           Cell cell = row.getCell(5);
           gyro.add(cell);

       }

       gyro.remove(0); //  because the first cell is String 
       for (Cell c : gyro) {
           System.out.println(c.getNumericCellValue());
       }

   }
```

Comment: So if the code works for one excel sheet works but not the other, you might want to add a screenshot of the excel sheets to help us understand the problem.

Comment: @LuckyBandit74 I added a screenshot of the Excelsheet

Comment: `Cell` indices in Apache POI are 0-based; do you want column G or something else?

Comment: @rgettman I  want to get D, E and F, but first i wanted to try first with one column. I changed `row.getCell(5);` but nothing changed. I get a `NullpointerException`

Comment: @LuckyBandit74 i have below a Foreach to print out the NumericCellValue. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Well firstly, the NullPointerException should be caught at a certain line of code, may you point out which line is causing the exception? And disregard what I said earlier

Comment: @LuckyBandit74 If a click on the exception it shows me the last line. The line ´System.out.println(c.getNumericCellValue());´. But in Debugmode i see the value of Cell what i insert in the arraylist is Null in the second time.

Comment: In the excel sheet, is row 2 a merged cell? If it is, I think that is considered as cell 0. Before the for-each loop, try adding another gyro.remove(0) as well to remove that Null cell. This is a guess and check situation: just keep trying to figure out where that Null cell is. In fact, just print out the gyro ArrayList after all information has been added to it. Use the print statement to your advatnage

Comment: your code needs to omit the values for the first 2 rows, not just 1 row - look at your screenshot, the data doesn't start until the 3rd row

Comment: @LuckyBandit74 @PJ Fanning No the row 2 its not merged. I put a System.out.println(cell.getCellType() in the while loop after the add Statement. it add the first row `Column6`. I also tried gyro.remove(0) and gyro.remove(1) but the exception is still there

Comment: I fixed a mistake in my earlier comment, do gyro.remove(0) twice. Do not remove 0 then 1 as that won’t remove the first 2 rows. The key here is that your data starts in the third row as @PJ Fanning mentioned

Comment: Thank you and @PJ Fanning Now the Exception is fixed. I get all the data now. I was wondereing that it didnt showed me the data before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to omit `NullPointerExceptions` just use `DataFormatter` to format the cells into `strings` for you. Regardless of the cell type, it will format it in the correct format and whenever the cells are `null`, it just returns an empty `string`.

e.g.

```java
DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();

for (Cell c : gyro) {
   System.out.println(dataFormatter.formatCellValue(c);
}
```

And debugging may help, set breakpoints whenever you have such problems.